# error: incompatible types: SupportSQLiteDatabase cannot be converted to AppDatabase

Tags: android-room

I am trying to include Room persistence library to my android project. I am using gradle dependency `android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1` library, not the `androidx`

I have tried changing the version to `1.1.0` & `1.1.0-beta2` but getting same error.

Gradle dependencies for Room:

`// Room components
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"`

Here `$rootProject.roomVersion` value is `1.1.1`

Support library version:

```
`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'`
```

The AppDatabase class:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import com.samcaraschools.userlistapp.module.User;
@Database(entities = {User.class},version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public static AppDatabase mDatabase;
    public abstract UserDao userDao();

    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (mDatabase == null) {
            synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
                if (mDatabase == null) {
                    mDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            AppDatabase.class, "word_database")
                            // Wipes and rebuilds instead of migrating
                            // if no Migration object.
                            // Migration is not part of this practical.
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return mDatabase;
    }
}
```

With the above code in place I am getting the following error:

`error: incompatible types: SupportSQLiteDatabase cannot be converted to AppDatabase`

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the name of the object of class AppDatabase. Rename it to any object name than mDatabase, then it will function properly.

If you check your AppDatabase_Impl.java, you will notice that mDatabase has error. This is because SupportSQLiteDatabase.java has object name mDatabase which gets override by the object name placed in AppDatabase.